# Condition-based counting of date from a list of dates

Tags: excel-formula

In a list of dates in `dd-mm-yyyy` format, how to count no. of days which are having specific condition for days or months or years? E. g., all dates with dates between 1st and 10th of the month?

Answer (score 0):

**Where `A1` is the date...**

> =IF(DAY(A1)<11,"1st - 10th", "11th - EOM")

---

**If you wanted this to be a conditional format you would:**

1. Navigate to: *Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format*
2. Use `=DAY(A1) < 11` to highlight dates that fall on 1st - 10th of month
3. Use `=DAY(A1) > 10` to highlight dates that fall past the 10th of month
4. Format to taste & apply to desired range

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Learning formulas in Excel.